# Android Studio shows old Image Assets

Tags: android, android-studio

When I overwrite an image asset in Android Studio, for example the default ic_launcher, the IDE keeps showing the old image - no matter what I do, the image is never refreshed in the IDE (the deployed app uses the correct one). After a while you are not sure which files you have already changed and which are to be changed. You can prepare a list and check the items, but it would be nice to see the actual files in the IDE.

Is there any way to force this incredibly buggy IDE to 'sync' the cached image resources with those actually chosen by the developer?

I am using Android Studio 1.1.

Cheers

Comment: @skizo Does this work for android studio version 1.1.0?

Comment: @TheJackal I bet yes, I solved the same problem doing this.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Your question has to be marked as a correct or just edit your question to see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Open your `src/drawable` folder and make sure that this `ic_launcher` is not in any folder of your drawable, it means that in your `mdpi`, `hdpi`, etc... folder is this icon, then you can delete it in each folder on your `drawable` or you can replace it with yours (with the same name, if you don't want to replace the ic_launcher on the whole code), and Clean / rebuild the project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already do that. I was asking for a way to avoid wasting time browsing the file system, deleting files, and creating/copying new image assets. If an editor allows a user to 'overwrite' resources, it should  realise by itself that the user has just overwritten some resources.